# Sharing files over internet for RPI

Tags: ftp, raspberry-pi

I am currently looking for someone to point me in the right direction. I need to connect to a Raspberry Pi over the internet so that I may add files to a specific folder from time to time.

I have installed tightVNC and I am able to log onto my Pi without a problem but I realized cannot share files between my PC and my Pi through TightVNC.

Since I am able to actually control my Pi remotely I first tried to used Google Drive on my Pi but that did not work through the browser same goes for my hotmail account or onedrive. I would like to set up a FTP server that would work over the internet but I am stuck and need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Might I recommend sftp instead? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sftp.md

Comment: Yes you may good sir

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to setup an FTP server just keep in mind that it will require additional ports allowed through firewall 21 for the FTP control channel and a few other depending on configuration for passive mode.

Basic instructions for FTP server for Raspberry PI can be found here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/step9/Install-an-FTP-server/

Side note:
SFTP might be easier as it will just use the same port as SSH.

Instructions for SFTP here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sftp.md

Comment: Why is SFTP not a good solution? It's built in and you have command-line as well as GUI clients. If you really do want FTP, they posted a link on how to install an FTP server too. What do you think might make this answer better?